# Owncloud Collabora with Docker Swarm not working

Tags: docker, owncloud, swarm

I am implementing Owncloud with Collabora using Docker Swarm, but I have several problems.

When I open a document for Collabora, I receive the following log:

```
[docbroker_003] WRN Poco::Net::DNS:: resolveOne ("IP") failed: Host not found: IP | wsd/Storage.cpp: 186
[docbroker_003] ERR loading document exception: Host not found | wsd/DocumentBroker.cpp: 1429
[docbroker_003] ERR Failed to add session to [/apps/richdocuments/wopi/files/14_ock7koz4yimw_0_0] with URI [http://IP:8080/apps/richdocuments/wopi/files/ 14_ock7koz4yimw_0_0 access_token = ALd4bQKRdCqBphrG73XEKZ7CgCiIbbW4 & access_token_ttl = 0]: Host not found | wsd/DocumentBroker.cpp: 1391
```

However, the host exists, and inside the container I can successfully curl this URL.

When I access Owncloud via DNS (not IP), I get this error

```
[docbroker_005] ERR No acceptable WOPI hosts found matching the target host [HOST] in config. | wsd/Storage.cpp: 292
[docbroker_005] ERR loading document exception: No acceptable WOPI hosts found matching the target host [HOST] in config. | wsd/DocumentBroker.cpp: 1429
[docbroker_005] ERR Failed to add session to [/apps/richdocuments/wopi/files/14_ock7koz4yimw_0_0] with URI [HOST:8080/apps/ richdocuments/wopi/files/14_ock7koz4yimw_0_0? access_token = X9wFvx_W_4_mhttp the target host [HOST] in config. | wsd/DocumentBroker.cpp: 1391
```

It only works if I put the container network as a host.

In another environment, using only Docker Compose (without Swarm) worked perfectly.

Any idea?

The images from Owncloud and Collabora are the latest in the hub. Docker is at version 18.09.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Add a line containing the IP regex in the loolwsd.xml file inside the  tag.

```
<wopi desc="Allow/deny wopi storage. Mutually exclusive with webdav." allow="true">
<host desc="Regex pattern of hostname to allow or deny." allow="true">localhost</host>
<host desc="Regex pattern of hostname to allow or deny." allow="true">10\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}</host>
<host desc="Regex pattern of hostname to allow or deny." allow="true">172\.1[6789]\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}</host>
<host desc="Regex pattern of hostname to allow or deny." allow="true">172\.2[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}</host>
<host desc="Regex pattern of hostname to allow or deny." allow="true">172\.3[01]\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}</host>
<host desc="Regex pattern of hostname to allow or deny." allow="true">172\.9[01]\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}</host>
<host desc="Regex pattern of hostname to allow or deny." allow="true">192\.168\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}</host>
<!--
host desc="Regex pattern of hostname to allow or deny." allow="true">[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}</host
-->
<host desc="Regex pattern of hostname to allow or deny." allow="false">192\.168\.1\.1</host>
<max_file_size desc="Maximum document size in bytes to load. 0 for unlimited." type="uint">0</max_file_size>
<reuse_cookies desc="When enabled, cookies from the browser will be captured and set on WOPI requests." type="bool" default="false">false</reuse_cookies>
<locking desc="Locking settings">
<refresh desc="How frequently we should re-acquire a lock with the storage server, in seconds (default 15 mins) or 0 for no refresh" type="int" default="900">900</refresh>
</locking>
</wopi>
```